# Can't write a byte array to file as hex

Tags: java, byte

I'm working on a project in java and I've been trying to write a byte array to a file (as hex values). I have tried everything I can think of, but it still seems to write out as strings instead of bytes (hex). Strangely, I am able to output other values to the same file in byte format (although these values are 'int's to begin with)

I am using RandomAccessFile to write the values, and have tried FileOutputStream and others but with the same result. I have been using the following method to write to the file:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#write(byte[])

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

[UPDATE]

```
          for (int x = 0; x <ascii.length; x++) {
          System.out.println(ascii[x]);
          writer.write(ascii[x]);
          }
```

This loop outputs the correct values to screen, but if I try to write them to file it writes them as ASCII...

Comment: Show us what you did and what you expect the file to contain, exactly.

Comment: Want to show one or more "things you tried to think of"?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Please, _please_, **please** show the output you want and the output you get, in both the console and in the file.

Comment: I'm debugging other things at the minute, but I will be back if I can't get it working.

Comment: Is anyone still following this?

Answer (score 1):

A file is made up of bytes. HEX is just a representation of those bytes. It has no meaning to the underlying storage.

With a HEX editor, you can look at the bytes in a file as HEX values. With a text editor, you can look at the bytes in a file as human readable characters (depending on the content and some character encoding).

In other words, you don't write HEX values to a file, unless you mean their representation, which will be the bytes generated from the `String` representation of the HEX value.

Comment: Yes, I want to write the hex value of the byte array to file, i.e. not an ASCII string.

Comment: @user Please edit your question and add an example of a short byte array and what bytes the file should contain after you've done the writing.